# conditional value in a hyperref textfield

Tags: macros, hyperref, ifthenelse, textfield

I am trying to create a TextField whose value is conditional on a boolean. If the boolean is true, the default value in the TextField is some value; if it is false, the TextField starts blank (the value is empty).

Here's my attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newboolean{withcorrect}   
\setboolean{withcorrect}{false}   

\newcommand{\correctAnsBlankPlain}[1]{%
\ifthenelse{\boolean{withcorrect}}{%
#1%
}{}%
}

\begin{document}

\correctAnsBlankPlain{5.0}

\TextField[name=H%
,value=\correctAnsBlankPlain{5.0}%
]{}

\end{document}
```

which yields the error "./exam.tex:21: Argument of \boolean has an extra }."

I know the `\correctAnsBlankPlain` command works, because when I comment out the line containing the value, it compiles fine. I can also make the `withcorrect` boolean `true` and see the 5.0 printed as expected before the TextField.

So, I assume that I'm doing something wrong by including a command within the optional argument of TextField, but I'm not sure 1) what or 2) how to best get around it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the commands in ifthen are not expandable and so unsuited in such places. Use e.g. the tools from etoolbox:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{withcorrect}
\setbool{withcorrect}{false}
\newcommand{\correctAnsBlankPlain}[1]{%
 \ifbool{withcorrect}{#1}{}}
\begin{document}

%\correctAnsBlankPlain{5.0}

\TextField[name=H1%
,value=\correctAnsBlankPlain{5.0}%
]{}

\setbool{withcorrect}{true}

\TextField[name=H2%
,value=\correctAnsBlankPlain{5.0}%
]{}

\end{document}
```

[image]